# How to get output 'xentop' or 'xm top' command in centOS

Tags: centos, xen

I would like to develop a shell script that gets a similar output as `top -c, w` or the `xmtop` or `xm top` commands and send the output to the command line or pipe into a file.

Answer (score 1):

Thank you for your points, finally i found the solution from the [Link](http://xen.1045712.n5.nabble.com/save-xm-top-output-td3390868.html)

```
    # xentop -b -i 2 -d 1 > /tmp/xentop

    # cat /tmp/xentop

          NAME  STATE   CPU(sec) CPU(%)     MEM(k) MEM(%)  MAXMEM(k) MAXMEM(%) VCPUS NETS NETTX(k) NETRX(k) VBDS   VBD_OO   VBD_RD   VBD_WR  VBD_RSECT  VBD_WSECT SSID
       usernam --b---         12    0.0     256000    6.3    4194304     103.4     1    1        8        0    2        0     2028       62      76244        592    0
      Domain-0 -----r         42    0.0    2103296   51.9   no limit       n/a     4    0        0        0    0        0        0        0          0          0    0
       vpsmans --b---         12    0.0     296960    7.3    4194304     103.4     1    1        4        0    2        0     3397      100      82356       1472    0
      superman --b---         10    0.0     256000    6.3    4194304     103.4     1    1        0        0    2        0     2413        0      46874
```